# Unity и сохранение результата на сервере (в облаке)

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.

Создаю игру на Unity для PC (Steam).

Нужно сохранять лучший результат.

Думал это реализуется так: арендуется целый сервер, ставится ПО туда и уже идет обмен от игру к серверу

Но сегодня услышал что можно использовать сервисы типа Google Play (и через API сохранять данные), но он для android.

Вопрос: есть универсальные сервисы для сохранения игровых данных / достижений? Нужно сохранять лучший результат уровня и загружать для отображения.

И подойдет ли steam api leaderboard ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираетесь публиковать игру только на Steam то решение использовать и интегрировать SteamSDK и хранить прогресс в Leaderbords или локально в файлах и синхронизировать их с акаунтом через Steam Cloud является хорошей идеей, как минимум из-за того что не нужно поддерживать свое решение для backend.

Нынешние магазины предоставляют api для того же leaderbord или achivements, что в свою очередь освобождает разработчика от забот поддержания своих серверов, а забот хватает, например наплыв пользователей и рост нагрузки.

Для steamsdk есть готовые решения которые облегчат интеграцию его в проект Unity, например https://steamworks.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Однажды натыкался на [вот такое чудо](http://playfab.com). Можете ещё посмотреть в сторону всяких платформ с флеш играми, у них обычно и для юнити есть апи. [Kongregate](http://docs.kongregate.com/docs/unity-api) например.